# RecyclerView do not refresh at all

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView does not update.Even when i call adapterNotifyDataSetChanged().Questions,and answers are loaded properly but items in recycler do not.

They just stay same,not even reordered.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText edit;
    Button provjeri;
    List<Item> questions;
    int curquestion=0;
    TextView pitanje;
    public List<String> suggestSource = new ArrayList<>();
    public static char[] user_submit_answer;
    public char[]answeri;
    String corect_answer;
    // data to populate the RecyclerView with
    String[]data = {"a","b","c","č","ć","d","đ","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"
            ,"n","o","p","r","s","š","t","u","v","z","ž"};
    String[]simpleArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        provjeri=findViewById(R.id.button);
        pitanje=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Random random=new Random();

        questions=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<Database.questions.length;i++){
            questions.add(new Item(Database.questions[i], answers[i]));
        }

        pitanje.setText(questions.get(curquestion).getQuestion());

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with
      // String[]data = {"a","b","c","č","ć","d","đ","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"
        //        ,"n","o","p","r","s","š","t","u","v","z","ž"};


        corect_answer=(questions.get(curquestion).getAnswer());

        answeri=corect_answer.toCharArray();
        user_submit_answer=new char[answeri.length];

        suggestSource.clear();
        for(char item:answeri)
        {
            //Add logo name to list
            suggestSource.add(String.valueOf(item));}

        for(int i = answeri.length; i< answeri.length*2; i++){
            suggestSource.add(data[random.nextInt(data.length)]);

        }
        Collections.shuffle(suggestSource);

        simpleArray = new String[ suggestSource.size() ];
        suggestSource.toArray( simpleArray );

        // set up the RecyclerView
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        int numberOfColumns = 6;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, simpleArray);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        provjeri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(edit.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(questions.get(curquestion).getAnswer())){
                    curquestion++;
                    pitanje.setText(questions.get(curquestion).getQuestion());
                    corect_answer=(questions.get(curquestion).getAnswer());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"blblblbl",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }else{

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"netacno",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }
        });
//("btw:why must write so much unnecesary text,to accept my question"and still not enough to post question,so wtf i must write some novel here,maybe make up some problems thath do not even exist,or just ....wtf maaaaaaaaan)//
```

Comment: Post content of **MyRecyclerViewAdapter**

Comment: Share your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody didnt answered,i found answer by myself.So the thing was i didnt refresh adapter after updating it,and it was called before it was created